# iPhone Bundle Display Name vs. Long Name?

Tags: iphone

I am creating two apps, let's call them Foo Bar and Foo Bar Pro.  When I install them and open iTunes, I see both apps there, but they both say Foo Bar because "Foo Bar Pro" won't fit as a bundle display name.  However, in iTunes, I want to see "Foo Bar" and "Foo Bar Pro".

I see a whole bunch of other apps with really long names in iTunes, and it's NOT what the Bundle Display Name shows up as.  For the life of me, tho, I can't figure out where that longer name is entered.  I assume in the Info.plist.

Can someone help? :-/

Answer (score 9):

I think it doesn't matter how many characters your name has since it is not of monospaced type. Try "wwwwwwwwwww" (11 chars) & "iiiiiiiiiiiiiii" (15 chars) and see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 8):

The long name you mention is **not** part of the App, **but rather meta-data in App Store**.

You set the long descriptive name after creating the app (or update to the app), but before you upload it. Once uploaded, you cannot edit the name until the next update.

See the attached screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 3):

The maximum character limit for any app name is 11. If the number of characters is more then 11, it will display "..." in name on the device. In iTunes, however, you can see full name. to change this you need to set the *Bunde Display Name* property in info.plist:

`Bundle display name: Foo Bar Pro`

And for project name you can try:

1. Go to Targets in Xcode
2. "Get Info" on your project's target (your current silly development name)
3. Search for "Product Name" under "Packaging".

   Change the value of that to whatever you want the program name to be.

Comment: The Product Name is FooBarPro.  There's no spaces, and it doesn't show up.

I definitely don't want to put Foo Bar Pro (the real name is longer) as the Bundle Display name, but how does the long name make it into iTunes?